# Video player alignment

Tags: joomla, media-player, mediaelement.js

I'm using the media player from `mediaelements.js` on `Joomla(yootheme)` and wanted to know how I could *center-align* the `player`, right now it's *left aligned*.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of your player you can use CSS as below:

```
#player{
    width:400px; /*example*/
    margin:0 auto; /*center align*/
}
```